# Putting closure

Tags: groovy, gradle

From [the documentation, 13.5.5](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#N10B52):

> When the last parameter of a method is a closure, you can place the
>   closure after the method call

Ok, I tried that, but it didn't exactly work as I was supposed. Consider the following code:

```
def repostiory_closure = {
    mavenCentral()
}

repositories{ //OK
    mavenCentral()
}

repositories(){ //OK
    mavenCentral()
}

repositories repostiory_closure //OK
repositories() repostiory_closure //compile-time error
```

So we can put the only a *closure literal* after a method call, but the variable of a `Closure` type. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is put the closure as an argument of the method call like so:

`repositories(repostiory_closure)`

So because the last argument is a closure the method can be called inline as above.